# How do I set ItemTemplate dynamically in WPF?

Tags: wpf, itemtemplate

Using WPF, I have a TreeView control that I want to set its ItemTemplate dynamically through procedural code.  How do I do this?  I assume I need to find the resource somewhere.

```
myTreeViewControl.ItemTemplate =   ??
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the template is defined in your <Window.Resources> section directly:

```
myTreeViewControl.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["SomeTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
```

If it's somewhere deep within your window, like in a <Grid.Resources> section or something, I think this'll work:

```
myTreeViewControl.ItemTemplate = this.FindResource("SomeTemplate") as DataTemplate;
```

And if it's elsewhere in your application, I *think* App.FindResource("SomeTemplate") will work.

Answer (score 2):

if your treeview control requires different templates for your items, you should implement DataTemplateSelector class and set it's instance to your tree view. as far as i remember there is a property of DataTemplateSelector.